# NGINX two domains SSL presents wrong cert

Tags: nginx, ssl, certificate, wildcard

I have two domains, both of which are wildcards. Both use https only eg.

*.example.something.com
*.example.com

The issue is that nginx seems to always present the default certificate (example.something.com), which is not valid, when I go to https://t12345.example.com.

My current nginx.conf file has the following entries:

```
server {

    listen 443   default_server;
    server_name   example.something.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/star.example.something.com.crt";
   ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/star.example.something.com.key";
}

server {

    listen 443   ssl;
    server_name   example.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/star.example.com.crt";
   ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/star.example.com.key";
}
```

No errors are reported by nginx and the certificates, which are both valid wildcard certificates are present.

Any ideas why it doesn't pick up the second certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't created a `server` block which matches the hostname you are trying to access, so nginx serves the request using the first `server` block with a matching `listen` directive.

To solve the problem, create a new `server` block or add the appropriate [`server_name`](https://nginx.org/r/server_name) to an existing `server` block.

If these are really wildcard certificates, and you want the single `server` block to handle every possible name, then you probably should be serving them with the wildcard name, i.e.:

```
server_name *.example.something.com;
```